# Prove/ Disprove: If $L$ is a CFL then $A(L)$ is a CFL too

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

Consider the operation $A(L)$:

$$A(L) = \{ w: w\in L \land w_R \notin L \}$$

where $w_R$ is the reverse of $w$.

> Prove/ Disprove: if $L$ is a CFL language so does $A(L)$.

I am almost certain there's a counter-example but I couldn't find a proper one. I'd be glad for help!

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your exercise for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple first step.

Consider any language $K \subseteq \{a,b\}^*$, and let $1,2$ be two new symbols. Let $L = 1\cdot \{a,b\}^* \cdot 2 \cup  2 \cdot  K \cdot 1$.

What if $1x2\in A(L)$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: First, try the following.  Prove/disprove: if $L$ is regular, then so is $A(L)$.

Another hint: That should help you narrow down your search for a counterexample.  Next, try to come up with a language that you know is context-free but not regular.  Try tweaking it a little bit so that it has a non-trivial intersection with its reversal.  What do you come up with?  I was able to very quickly solve this problem using this approach -- the first example language I came up with, and the first modification I tried, worked.